# how can I use add_action with external class which the function contain 2 argument?

Tags: actions

I create a file name `custom.php` which is like below:

```
class customClass{ 
   function dothisfunction( $mobiles , $message ){
      //use parameters
   }
 }
```

In my `function.php`  file I add the following code:

```
$number = '09112223344';
$mymsg = 'nadia is testing';
$myClass = new customClass();
add_action( 'publish_post', array( $myClass ,'dothisfunction', $number, $mymsg ) );
```

but it returns error, the error is :

> **PHP Warning**:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 288

How can I solve it? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `publish_post` post takes two arguments first is `$ID` of the post that is being published and the second is the `$post` instance ([See codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post)). I modified your code a bit below.

Your class is almost identical just renamed the parameters of the function to not cause confusion.

```
class customClass{ 
   function dothisfunction( $ID, $post ){
      echo "something";
   }
 }
```

No need for the `$number` and `$mymsg` in the array() because you only need to specify instance and the method to be used of the instance.

```
$myClass = new customClass();
add_action( 'publish_post', array( $myClass ,'dothisfunction' ), 10, 2 );
```

Also, you should specify how much parameters you are passing to `dothisfunction` in [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) as 4th parameter.

Comment: here is new problem with this change i want to call this function once, when new post publish but the function will be run multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

To hook your method `dothisfunction` to action `publish_post`, you should use [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) this way:

```
$myClass = new customClass();
add_action( 'publish_post', array( $myClass, 'dothisfunction' ), 10, 2 );
```

The number of arguments accepted by the function is specified in the 4th parameter of `add_action()`.

However, this number can not be greater than the number of arguments passed in [`do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/), because it is the **`do_action()`** that **decides how many and what arguments** will be passed to the functions hooked to specific action hook.

More about actions you can read [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/).

Comment: that's great but the problem is before new post , even if I just click the post the function trigger multiple times! i just want it to be run when i put a new post !

Comment: @Nadia You can use [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) (for any type) or [`save_post_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) hook (for specific post type) and check if `$update` argument is FALSE.  `add_action( 'save_post_POST_TYPE', array( $myClass, 'dothisfunction' ), 10, 4 );`